# Add Public Groups as criteria to a Process Builder

Tags: process-builder, user, public-group, criteria

I want my process builder to run just for set of users.

I know that I can do it to run for certain profiles/ Roles but not all people in that profile/ roles need to run it.

**Is there a way to add 'Public Groups' to the criteria element in Process Builder?**

I want to avoid having to put each user's ID in the criteria...

Comment: No you can't achieve in standard way, 1) You can create a field on User object OR 2) Write a apex code and run the action functionality 3)  Go for trigger rather than process builder

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way for it to reference public groups but there is a way for Process Builder to reference custom permissions in the criteria. Custom permissions are admin defined and can be added to a permission set and thus relate to a specific set of users. They can also be used in Process Builder criteria formulae using the $Permission system variable.

1. Create custom permission
2. Create permission set that contains this custom permission
3. Apply this permission set to a set of users
4. Include the $Permission in your process criteria

You can read an example of this [here](https://jenwlee.wordpress.com/2016/06/07/using-custom-permissions-in-process-builder/).